# The "Responsive filemanager" plugin does not work ”- Plugin for TinyMCE 5

Tags: javascript, tinymce, responsive-filemanager, tinymce-5

I apologize for my English, but I translate it with google translate.

I am trying to install the "Responsive File Manager" plugin (https://www.responsivefilemanager.com/)
I moved the files according to the instructions and configured. When I press the popup button, an error in the console pops up.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhGFg.png)

The "filemanager" directory was transferred to "*/admin/wysiwyg/new_tinymce/*". In this directory there is TinyMCE

The "plugins" directory was transferred to "*/admin/wysiwyg/new_tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/*".

I moved the other files and directories to "*/admin/wysiwyg/new_tinymce/*".

Here is the structure of files and directories:

```
website
-admin
--wyswig
---new_tinymce
----filemanager
-----config
-----css
-----img
-----include
-----js
-----Other files and directories from filemanager
----js
-----tinymce
------langs
------plugins
-------responsivefilemanager
------skins
------jquery.tinymce.min
------license.txt
------tinymce.js
------tinymce.min.js
----source
----src
----tools
----changelog.txt
----Gruntfile.js
----LICENSE.TXT
----packpage.json
----packpage-lock.json
----readme.md
----yarn.lock
```

I have omitted some files and directories that are not important.

Calling TinyMce. I have specifically omitted unnecessary entries to make the code more readable:

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        image_prepend_url: file_dir, // ścieżka do katalogu z plikami / zdjeciami itp
        image_caption: true, //Dodaje możliwość podpisania obrazu. Używa do tego znaczników html5
        image_advtab: true, // dodanie karty z zaawansowanymi opcjami do okna dodawania obrazka
        image_title: true, // Dodanie opcji tytułu do obrazka do okna dodawania obrazka

        external_filemanager_path:"/admin/wysiwyg/new_tinymce/filemanager/",
        filemanager_title:"Responsive Filemanager" ,
        external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "/admin/wysiwyg/new_tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/responsivefilemanager/plugin.min.js"},
        //filemanager_crossdomain: true,

        plugins: [
            'importcss', //Gdy jest aktywowane, nie działa zakładka akapit //TODO
            'advlist autoresize autolink lists link image imagetools charmap preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker',
            //'responsivefilemanager',
            'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars responsivefilemanager code autosave',
            'insertdatetime media nonbreaking table directionality',
            'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern codesample print',
            'directionality emoticons help hr'
            //toc - todo -  trzeba ostylować wszystko w css - generalnie dodaje spis trzesci na podstawie nagłówków znalezionych w tekscie. - https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/toc/
            //directionality - pisanie od lewej do prawej i na odwrót
        ],
        toolbar: [
            'bold italic underline strikethrough | forecolor backcolor | bullist numlist outdent indent | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | removeformat subscript superscript',
            'blockquote template codesample restoredraft| code print preview | cut copy paste searchreplace spellchecker toc',
            'ltr rtl',
            //pisanie od lewej do prawej i na odwrót
            'undo redo | hr emoticons media link responsivefilemanager image nonbreaking pagebreak |styleselect  fontselect fontsizeselect| mybutton mybutton2 mybutton3'
        ],

    });
```

When clicking on the file manager icon, the error shows me in the console [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5Pxb.png):

```
plugin.js:84 Uncaught TypeError: editor.windowManager.openUrl is not a function
    at Object.openmanager [as onAction] (plugin.js:84)
    at theme.js:21482
    at theme.js:9575
    at theme.js:21480
    at theme.js:2457
    at each (theme.js:267)
    at run (theme.js:2456)
    at theme.js:2969
    at theme.js:56
    at theme.js:10825
```